# Multilingual bibliography using biblatex-gost packege

Tags: biblatex

I'm using GOST bibliography and citation style in an article document. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{mathtext} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt,maxcitenames=2,style=gost-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{GOST.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\author{Автор}
\title{Название\thanks{ссылка на грант}}
\date{}
\maketitle
\section{Первый раздел}
Some text \cite{reverberi2012deduction}. More text \cite{lisanyuketal}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image: PDF]
As you can see, the bibliography contains items in two languages, English and Russian. The problem arises when dealing with the item in English with more than two authors (first in the list), namely LaTeX puts the name of the first author *after* the title. Similar item in Russian (the last in the list), on the other hand, looks fine. In the .bib file both items have absolutely identical form:

```
@article{quiroga2012concept,
  title={Concept cells: the building blocks of declarative memory functions},
  author={Quiroga, Rodrigo Quian},
  journal={Nature Reviews Neuroscience},
  volume={13},
  number={8},
  pages={587--597},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@article{reverberi2012deduction,
    title={Deduction without awareness},
    author={Reverberi, Carlo and Pischedda, Doris and Burigo, Michele and Cherubini, Paolo},
    journal={Acta psychologica},
    volume={139},
    number={1},
    pages={244--253},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{yuste2015neuron,
    title={From the neuron doctrine to neural networks},
    author={Yuste, Rafael},
    journal={Nature Reviews Neuroscience},
    volume={16},
    number={8},
    pages={487--497},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@article{zaitsev,
    title={Схемы аргументации: игры риторического mind’a или источник общезначимости аргументативных рассуждений?},
    author={Зайцев, Дмитрий Владимирович},
    journal={РАЦИО.ru},
    volume={4},
    number={2},
    pages={57--77},
    year={2010},
    publisher={БФУ им. И. Канта}
}



@article{mikirtumov,
    title={Аргументация и легитимность: дело Маркина},
    author={Микиртумов, Иван Борисович},
    journal={РАЦИО.ru},
    volume={15},
    number={1},
    pages={97--133},
    year={2015},
    publisher={БФУ им. И. Канта}
}

@article{lisanyuketal,
    title={From the neuron doctrine to neural networks},
    author={Лисанюк, Елена Николаевна and Грфцова, Ирина Николаевна and Мигунов, Анатолий Иванович},
    journal={Журнал по аргументации},
    volume={16},
    number={8},
    pages={487--497},
    year={2015}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I believe that the behaviour of putting only the first author after the title if there are four or more authors is intentional and will happen regardless of the language.

Comment: @moewe indeed, according to GOST style items with four or more authors should be specified this way (i didn't know that till now), i.e. title first. However, all the authors should be listed, not only the first one.

Comment: I got a similar problem recently and think that to make the bibliography according to GOST manually would be better (`\begin{thebibliography}{99}...\end{thebibliography}`)

Comment: @OlgaK maybe it is true if you are creating an article or any other _single_ document. But, since I'm trying to make an article _template_ for a scientific journal, making bibliography manually is not a good option.

Comment: I see, then you have to solve that. But I think it is not so easy

Comment: Try setting `maxbibnames=999` or something similar as option.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `maxbibnames=999` option resolved the issue. Thanks to @moewe.

Comment: Next time, please first ask the person, who gave the comment, if he/she wants to convert the comment into an answer himself. That way, he gets the reputation he deserves for the answer.